# How can I use different color palettes for different layers in ggplot2?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, palette

Is it possible to plot two sets of data on the same plot, but use different color palettes for each set?

```
testdf <- data.frame( x = rnorm(100), 
                  y1 = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                  y2 = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1),
                  yc = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 3))
ggplot(testdf, aes(x, y1, colour = yc)) + geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y = y2))
```

What I would like to see is one set of data, say `y1`, in blues (color set by `yc`), and the other set in reds (again color set by `yc`).

The legend should then show 2 color scales, one in blue, the other red.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you translate the "blues" and "reds" to varying transparency, then it is not against ggplot's philosophy. So, using [Thierry's `Molten`version of the data set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428869/755257):

```
ggplot(Molten, aes(x, value, colour = variable, alpha = yc)) + geom_point()
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible with ggplot2. I think it against the philosophy of ggplot2 because it complicates the interpreatation of the plot.

Another option is to use different shapes to separate the points.

```
testdf <- data.frame( x = rnorm(100), 
                      y1 = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                      y2 = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1),
                      yc = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 3))
Molten <- melt(testdf, id.vars = c("x", "yc"))
ggplot(Molten, aes(x, value, colour = yc, shape = variable)) + geom_point()
```