# Different colour palettes for two different colour aesthetic mappings in ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363035/ggplot2-how-to-specify-multiple-fill-colors-for-points-that-are-connected-by-li) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757394/overplotting-with-different-colour-palettes-in-ggplot2) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427950/how-can-i-use-different-color-palettes-for-different-layers-in-ggplot2) question. I have a scatterplot (using `geom_point`) coloured by a factor, using a particular colour palette. I'm using `stat_smooth` to draw certain smoothing lines through the points, grouped by *another* factor. I'd like these lines to use a different colour palette.

Here is a [Dropbox link to some example data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/08zponb87c7mq59/SO_data?dl=0). Just do a

```
currDT <- read.table("SO_data", sep = "|", header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

I usually have my data in a data.table, so you might find it helpful change that as well. Oh and here is the colour scheme I'm using at the moment, you can use `scale_colour_brewer` to generate your own, I'm just including this for completeness.

```
my_col_scheme <- c("#e41a1c", "#377eb8", "#4daf4a", "#984ea3", "#ff7f00", "#7B8A7B",
    "#0B29D6", "#f781bf", "#999999", "black")
```

Hopefully that is clear enough. Here is some example code:

```
icorr_elec <- ggplot(currDT,
                aes(x = EFP, y = SAPT), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Anion, shape = Cation),  size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = my_col_scheme) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + 0, aes(linetype = Halide, colour = Halide), 
            alpha = 0.8, size = 0.5, level = 0) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("dotdash", "F1"),
                      breaks = c("hal", "non-hal"), labels = c("Halides", "Non-Halides"))
```

How can this be done in ggplot2? From the other questions I gathered I could specify each line manually, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Would you mind adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Your question looks interesting, but I don't want to create a dummy dataset to take a look at it.

Comment: @RichardErickson thanks for your interest, if you need more information I'd be glad to provide it, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the example. As an FYI, I had to delete the space from `sep = "|"`.  I don't know if it's my computer or some other error (I'm on a Mac right now). Also, out of curiosity, where are you getting this data from? Is it coming of an instrument? I've never seen a `|` used as a separator.

Comment: @RichardErickson No, I just wrote the data.table to a text file using `write.table`. I know that commas and whitespace are more common separators, but these sometimes appear in data, especially character/string types, whereas this is a much rarer character, hence I usually use it as a field separator.

Comment: I gave it my best shot below, but couldn't figure it out. Good luck. (BTW, I like `data.table` as well!).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get separate color mappings for the lines and the points by using a filled point marker for the points and mapping that to the `fill` aesthetic, while keeping the lines mapped to the `colour` aesthetic. Filled point markers are those numbered 21 through 25 (see `?pch`). Here's an example, adapting @RichardErickson's code:

```
ggplot(currDT, aes(x = EFP, y = SAPT), na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + 0, 
              aes(linetype = Halide, colour = Halide), 
              alpha = 0.8, size = 0.5, level = 0) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("dotdash", "F1"),
                        breaks = c("hal", "non-hal"), labels = c("Halides", "Non-Halides")) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Anion, shape = Cation),  size = 3, alpha = 0.4, colour="transparent") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_col_scheme) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=my_col_scheme[1:8],
                                                 shape=15, size=3)),
         shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=c(21,24), fill="black", size=3)),
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c("dotdash", "F1"))),
         linetype = FALSE)
```

Here's an explanation of what I've done:

1. In `geom_point`, change `colour` aesthestic to `fill`. Also, put `colour="transparent"` outside of `aes`. That will get rid of the border around the points. If you want a border, set it to whatever border color you prefer.
2. In `scale_colour_manual`, I've set the colors to blue and red, but you can, of course, set them to whatever you prefer.
3. Add `scale_fill_manual` to set the colors of the points using the `fill` aesthetic.
4. Add `scale_shape_manual` and set the values to 21 and 24 (filled circles and triangles, respectively).
5. All the stuff inside `guides()` is to modify the legend. I'm not sure why, but without these overrides, the legends for fill and shape are blank. Note that I've set `fill="black"` for the `shape` legend, but it's showing up as gray. I don't know why, but without `fill="somecolor"` the `shape` legend is blank. Finally, I overrode the `colour` legend in order to include the linetype in the colour legend, which allowed me to get rid of the redundant `linetype` legend. I'm not totally happy with the legend, but it was the best I could come up with without resorting to special-purpose grobs.

[image]

**NOTE:** I changed `color=NA` to `color="transparent"`, as `color=NA` (in version 2 of ggplot2) causes the points to disappear completely, even if you use a point with separate border and fill colors. Thanks to @aosmith for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564379/how-can-i-use-different-color-or-linetype-aesthetics-in-same-plot-with-ggplot).

Comment: Good job! I'm impressed at the amount of hacking you had to do to make `ggplot` give you the plot you got. I tried using fill, but didn't realized I also had to change `color` to `NA`.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the work was in wrestling with the legend. You only need to include `colour=NA` if you don't want a border around the points. If you don't mind a border you can omit `colour=NA` and get a black border, or you can set the color to whatever you prefer.

Comment: Cheers! That was pretty smart, using `fill` instead of `colour`. I wouldn't have had played around with `guides` long enough to get the legend I want. This does the job. For now at least, because I'm always open to other methods.

Comment: Interestingly, using `fill` instead of `colour` for `geom_point` only works if you *also* specify `shape` either inside or outside `aes`.

Comment: Yes, you have to use a point marker that has separate border and fill. Shape 21 through 25 have that characteristic. See the first paragraph and item 4 in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `ggplot2` will let you change color twice and update the legend. I seem to recall reading that you cannot change `scale_color_manual` twice in a plot. I couldn't find that webpage, but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427950/how-can-i-use-different-color-palettes-for-different-layers-in-ggplot2) touches on the topic. I also tried using the suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778612/change-color-for-two-geom-point-in-ggplot2), but that didn't work. Probably because we're trying to mix `geoms` (but that's just a guess).

I can get either the regression lines colored:

```
part1 <- 
    ggplot(currDT,
           aes(x = EFP, y = SAPT), na.rm = TRUE) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + 0, 
                aes(linetype = Halide, colour = Halide), 
                alpha = 0.8, size = 0.5, level = 0) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("dotdash", "F1"),
                          breaks = c("hal", "non-hal"), 
                          labels = c("Halides", "Non-Halides")) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", 'blue'),
                       labels = c("Halides", "Non-Halides"))
    ggsave('part1.jpeg', part1)
```

[image]
Or the data points to plot:

```
part2 <-           
    ggplot(currDT,
           aes(x = EFP, y = SAPT), na.rm = TRUE) +     
    geom_point(aes(color = Anion, shape = Cation),  size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("dotdash", "F1"),
                          breaks = c("hal", "non-hal"), 
                          labels =c("Halides", "Non-Halides")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = my_col_scheme)   
    ggsave('part2.jpeg', part2)
```

[image]
But not both:

```
both <- 
    ggplot(currDT,
           aes(x = EFP, y = SAPT), na.rm = TRUE) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + 0, 
                aes(linetype = Halide, colour = Halide), 
                alpha = 0.8, size = 0.5, level = 0) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("dotdash", "F1"),
                      breaks = c("hal", "non-hal"), labels = c("Halides", "Non-Halides")) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Anion, shape = Cation),  size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = my_col_scheme)                    
ggsave('both.jpeg', both)
```

[image]

I think you're going to need to add each line manual. Hopefully somebody else knows how to answer this, but I don't think @hadley allows both colors to changed. Luckily, you're `data.table` so it should be easy to do :-)

**Comment to anybody else trying to solve this** Hopefully my partial answer helps you to answer this question. Also, my third figure shows how `ggplot2` isn't getting the legend color <strike>correct</strike> as the OP wants it. As another tip, you might try playing around with the legend options.

Comment: print `part 1` with the halide/non-halide legend of the correct colours in the right place, then print `both` with that legend disabled, a transparent background, and the cation and halide legends positioned so that they don't overlap the first legend?

Comment: wow thanks for your effort! yeah, that was basically where I ended up before I asked this question; by the way, which colours are ggplot2 using for the lines? it doesn't seem to be using `my_col_scheme`
@geryan are you suggesting creating two plots then layering them one on top of the other? Can this be done in R itself or will we be looking at an outside image manipulation program?

Comment: @SamuelTan, yes, that is what I was suggesting, but I tried it with some of my own code and can't make it work, sorry.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to include you color code. I was changing it and forgot to add it back in.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness sake - adding two scales for the same aesthetic is now easily possible with the `ggnewscale` package

Comment: Wonderful, for me this is the most appropriate answer :) For future reference, it is as easy as loading `library(ggnewscale)` and inserting, e.g., `new_scale_colour()` in between the calls to _ggplot_ geoms.