# How can I use different color or linetype aesthetics in same plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a plot with ggplot that uses colored points, vertical lines, *and* horizontal lines to display the data. Ideally, I'd like to use two different color or linetype scales for the `geom_vline` and `geom_hline` layers, but ggplot discourages/disallows multiple variables mapped to the same aesthetic.

```r
# Create example data
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1234)
example.df <- data_frame(dt = seq(ymd("2016-01-01"), ymd("2016-12-31"), by="1 day"),
                         value = rnorm(366),
                         grp = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 366, replace=TRUE))

date.lines <- data_frame(dt = ymd(c("2016-04-01", "2016-10-31")),
                         dt.label = c("April Fools'", "Halloween"))

value.lines <- data_frame(value = c(-1, 1),
                          value.label = c("Threshold 1", "Threshold 2"))
```

If I set linetype aesthetics for both `geom_*line`s, they get put in the
linetype legend together, which doesn't necessarily make logical sense

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(x=dt, y=value, colour=grp)) +
  geom_hline(data=value.lines, aes(yintercept=value, linetype=value.label)) +
  geom_vline(data=date.lines, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(dt), linetype=dt.label)) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  scale_x_date() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Alternatively, I could set one of the lines to use a colour aesthetic,
but then that again puts the legend lines in an illogical legend
grouping

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(x=dt, y=value, colour=grp)) +
  geom_hline(data=value.lines, aes(yintercept=value, colour=value.label)) +
  geom_vline(data=date.lines, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(dt), linetype=dt.label)) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  scale_x_date() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The only partial solution I've found is to use a fill aesthetic instead
of colour in `geom_point`and setting `shape=21` to use a fillable shape,
but that forces a black border around the points. I can get rid of the
border by manually setting `color="white`, but then the white border
covers up points. If I set `colour=NA`, no points are plotted.

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(x=dt, y=value, fill=grp)) +
  geom_hline(data=value.lines, aes(yintercept=value, colour=value.label)) +
  geom_vline(data=date.lines, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(dt), linetype=dt.label)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=2, colour="white") +
  scale_x_date() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

This might be a case where ggplot's "you can't have two variables mapped
to the same aesthetic" rule can/should be broken, but I can't figure out clean way around it. Using fill with `geom_point` shows the most promise, but there's no way to remove the point borders.

Any ideas for plotting two different color or linetype aesthetics here?

Comment: This seems like a case where directly labeling the lines would be clearer anyway...

Comment: Using `fill` for the points is the way to go (see, for example, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29958948/496488). To remove the borders, include `color=NA` inside `geom_point`, through I agree with @Gregor that just labeling the lines directly would probably be better than using color for them.

Comment: I think you need `color = "transparent"`

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. I see that `color=NA` no longer works (the points are not plotted, even if you specify a fill color). So, it's either `color="transparent"` or a transparent "color" like `color="#00000000"`.

Comment: Yeah `color=NA` inside `geom_point()` removes all the points—they need some sort of color to plot. `color = "transparent"` fixes everything, though.