# ggplot scale_color_manual ignored

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm trying to plot two sets of data onto a single plot: one set (the BATH geom_text) to display 4 models' measurements, and another set (the geom_points) to display 77 different users' measurements.

```
preBATH<- monophs_allcoded %>%
filter(class == 'BATH') %>%
  group_by(user, model)%>%
  summarize(mean_pre_f1 = mean(f1_scaled_pre), mean_post_f1 = mean(f1_scaled_post), mean_pre_f2 = mean(f2_scaled_pre), mean_post_f2= mean(f2_scaled_post), model_f1 = mean(f1avg_scaledMODEL), model_f2 = mean(f2avg_scaledMODEL))%>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x= model_f2, y = model_f1, label = 'BATH', color=model))+
  geom_point(aes(x= mean_pre_f2, y = mean_pre_f1, color =user))+
  scale_color_manual(values=allcolors)+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol = 1)) +
  expand_limits(x = c(0,2000)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(0,600))  +
   xlab("Lobanov-normalized and scaled f2")+
  ylab("Lobanov-normalized and scaled f1")

preBATH <- preBATH + scale_y_reverse()
preBATH <- preBATH + scale_x_reverse()
```

[image: output of ggplot preBATH]

Ideally, I would like two separate color aesthetic mappings for each set of measurements. From what I have gathered, ggplot won't allow this. I've come up with a workaround, by generating a set of colors and specifying the first four as colors I want to use for the model measurements (`allcolors`) and specifying the colors manually in this line;

```
 scale_color_manual(values=allcolors)+
```

However, ggplot seems to ignore this command. I've tried `scale_fill_manual` with no luck. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: I believe it needs to be scale_colour_manual, color with a 'u'.

Comment: as a UK English speaker, this would be ironic if true - but that's not working either. Thanks.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to say. What are the values of `user` or `model`? Try providing an example dataset and the minimum amount of code needed to generate the issue you're having.

Comment: @stevebroll `scale_color_manual` and `scale_colour_manual` are the same commands.

Comment: You can’t map an aesthetic to more than one variable. And all the ggplot functions allow both spellings of color.

Comment: That explains it, thank-you. Do you have any suggestions for how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Well, you're using the same text label ("BATH") for each model. Why not simply use the name of the model as the text label?

Comment: I considered this, but this is one of 10 similar plots for different words, so wanted to include the word itself. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Use a filled point marker for the points (`shape=21` for filled circles) and then use `fill=user` in `geom_point`. But having, effectively, two color scales in the graph will probably be confusing.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29958948/496488) of using filled points to create the effect of two different color mappings.