# How to have 2 color schemes in ggplot geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I would like to plot 2 different columns and color each one base on groups in another column. I would also like that the color will be different for each series.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957669/different-colour-palettes-for-two-different-colour-aesthetic-mappings-in-ggplot2/29958948#29958948) but I cant get it to work.

What am I doing:

```
tbl <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 9), y1 = rnorm(9, 10), y2=rnorm(9, 50), class=c(rep("A", 3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3)))

ggplot(data = tbl, aes(x=x, y=y1)) + geom_point(aes(col=class)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "lightblue", "purple")) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2, fill=class)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "lightgreen", "darkgreen"))
```

somehow the fill is not showing. I also tried with `color="transparent"` but that just make the series to disappear.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the `ggnewscale` package. Just insert `new_scale_colour()+` before defining your second color scheme:

```
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

tbl_long %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    aes(x, value, colour=class),
    filter(tbl_long, name=="y1"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "lightblue", "purple")) +
  labs(colour = "y1") +
  new_scale_colour()+
  geom_point(
    aes(x, value, colour=class),
    filter(tbl_long, name=="y2"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "lightgreen", "darkgreen")) +
  labs(colour = "y2")
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks!