# How to add legend manually without overwriting the others legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

First, below is my code

```
library(ggplot2)

x1 <- rnorm(200)
x2 <- rnorm(200,2,1) 

y <- ifelse(1 + 3*x1 - x2 > 0, "1 + 3*x1 - x2 > 0", "1 + 3*x1 - x2 < 0")
z <- ifelse(-2 + x1 + 2*x2 > 0, "-2 + x1 + 2*x2 > 0", "-2 + x1 + 2*x2 < 0")
dat <- data.frame(x1,x2,y,z)
ggplot(data = dat) + geom_point(aes(x1,x2, col = y, shape = z)) + 
geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = 3, color="red", size=1.5) +  
geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = -0.5, col = "green", size = 1.5)
```

[image]

**I want to add another legend** with:

- title = "Hyperplanes"
- red solid line = "1 + 3*x1 - x2 = 0"
- green solid line = "-2 + x1 + 2*x2 = 0"
- position = bottom of the plot

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't use ggplot, so there could actually be an easier way to do this, see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29958948/2994949) with a bit of a hacky answer (although it is an old question) like the one below.

```
library('ggplot2')
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(200)
x2 <- rnorm(200,2,1) 

y <- ifelse(1 + 3*x1 - x2 > 0, "1 + 3*x1 - x2 > 0", "1 + 3*x1 - x2 < 0")
z <- ifelse(-2 + x1 + 2*x2 > 0, "-2 + x1 + 2*x2 > 0", "-2 + x1 + 2*x2 < 0")
dat <- data.frame(x1,x2,y,z)

p1 <- ggplot(data = dat) + geom_point(aes(x1,x2, col = y, shape = z)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = 3, color="red", size=1.5) +  
  geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = -0.5, col = "green", size = 1.5)
p1

dd <- data.frame(
  x1 = NA_real_, x2 = NA_real_,
  label = c('-2 + x1 + 2*x2 = 0', '1 + 3*x1 - x2 = 0')
)

p2 <- ggplot(dd, aes(x1, x2, color = label)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = '', y = '', color = 'Hyperplanes') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'red')) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0), legend.direction   = 'horizontal',
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'))

library('patchwork')
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(heights = c(1, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Great Job. Wasn't aware that this works. My approach to tackle similar problems always included extracting the legend via cowplot as an intermediate step then glueing only the legend via pw. :D But yours is much easier.